# Can access property of object in mapped array (Next.js)

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to map through an array of objects and return a link property as a `<li></li>` but for some reason nothing is being returned:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Config } from "../../config";

export default function Navbar() {
  const [navs, setNavs] = useState();
  const [mainNav, setMainNav] = useState();
  const [links, setLinks] = useState();

  useEffect(async () => {
    const res = await fetch(`${Config.apiUrl}/navs`);
    const data = await res.json();
    setNavs(data);
    // !!navs && setMainNav(navs.map((x) => (x.name === "main-nav" ? x : null)));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    !!navs && setMainNav(navs.map((x) => (x.name === "main-nav" ? x : null)));
    !!mainNav && setLinks(mainNav.map((item) => item.link));
  }, [navs]);

  !!links && console.log(links);

  return (
    <nav>
      <ul>{!!links && links.map((item) => <li>{item.link}</li>)}</ul>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

The result of my `console.log(links)` shows the following output:

```
[
  {
     _id: "5f975d6d7484be510af56903", link: "home", url: "/", __v: 0, id: "5f975d6d7484be510af56903"
  },
  {
     _id: "5f975d6d7484be510af56904", link: "posts", url: "/posts", __v: 0, id: "5f975d6d7484be510af56904"
  },
]
```

I don't see why I can access the `link` property through `item.link`.

P.S. This is starting too look far from elegant, does anyone else have any idea how I can clean this up more?

Comment: Can u share what u get as "data" i.e result of api call?

Comment: Can you console log your `data` and add it here. That will help us debug the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here,

```
useEffect(() => {
    !!navs && setMainNav(navs.map((x) => (x.name === "main-nav" ? x : null)));
    !!mainNav && setLinks(mainNav.map((item) => item.link));
}, [navs]);
```

The problem is you are using mainNav from state right after you are setting the value in state in the above useEffect. It doesn't wait for the state to be updated and then take the result. You have two options here,

Either declare another useEffect like this,

```
useEffect(() => {
    !!navs && setMainNav(navs.map((x) => (x.name === "main-nav" ? x : null)));
}, [navs]);

useEffect(() => {
    !!mainNav && setLinks(mainNav.map((item) => item.link));
}, [mainNav]);
```

Or you can store the mainNav in a variable at first. Like this,

```
useEffect(() => {
    let mainNavData = [];
    if(!!navs) {
         mainNavData = navs.map((x) => (x.name === "main-nav" ? x : null));
         setMainNav(mainNavData);   
         setLinks(mainNavData.map((item) => item.link));
    }
}, [navs]);
```

Comment: So I tried the **first option**: nothing rended to the page and the `console.log` logged the array 6 times (instead of 3). I tried the **second option** you gave: nothing rendered to the page and the `console.log` logged an empty object 3 times. None of them worked.

Comment: There was an issue with the 2nd option. It should throw some error. Please try again. Updated the 2nd solution.

Comment: So the **second option** is now returning a `console.log` 3 times, twice with an empty array and once with the populated array. It didn render anything to the page either.